# How to use one else statement with multiple if statements

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a login prompt and I want it to print 'Success' only if there are no errors. This is the code I'm using:

```
if not is_email(email) or not is_name(name) or password != confirmPassword or not is_secure(password):
    if not is_email(email):
        print('Not a valid email')
    if not is_name(name):
        print('Not a valid name')
    if password != confirmPassword:
        print('Passwords don\'t match')
    if not is_secure(password):
        print('Password is not secure')
else:
    print('Success')
```

Would there be any way to make this code shorter? I want to make it show all the errors at once so I'm not using elif.

Comment: You will need a boolean flag as extra variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
flags = [is_email(email), is_name(name), password != confirmPassword, is_secure(password)]
prints = ['Not a valid email', 'Not a valid name', 'Passwords don\'t match', 'Password is not secure']

for index in range(len(flags)):
    if flags[index] == False:
        print(prints[index])
```

Comment: I think that this one will be the most useful for me instead of just using a flag because it isn't repetitive thanks!

Comment: Note that a common mistake for beginning programmers is to favour short code over fast or easily readable code, both of which should trump brevity. There's nothing wrong with this solution, but you should realise that it in fact needs more code to be executed, so it saves the computer no work and will be slightly slower, in addition to being a bit harder to understand for anyone first reading the source.

Comment: ok I understand now but how would I go about it if I wanted to have a lot of different conditions.

Answer (score 4):

A way to avoid repeating the tests:

```
ok = True
if not is_email(email):
    print('Not a valid email')
    ok = False
if not is_name(name):
    print('Not a valid name')
    ok = False
if password != confirmPassword:
    print('Passwords don\'t match')
    ok = False
if not is_secure(password):
    print('Password is not secure')
    ok = False
if ok:
    print('Success')
```

It's not shorter, but it's clear and saves the extra comparisons, so it's faster and not as wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a flag:

```
has_errors = False

if not is_email(email):
    print(...)
    has_errors = True
...

if not has_errors:
    print("Success!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: accumulate the errors into a list, and then you can check the error list for truthiness instead of re-checking all the error conditions.  This also saves you from having to maintain another piece of state and have another line of code in each `if` block to update it.

```
errors = []
if not is_email(email):
    errors.append('Not a valid email')
if not is_name(name):
    errors.append('Not a valid name')
if password != confirmPassword:
    errors.append('Passwords don\'t match')
if not is_secure(password):
    errors.append('Password is not secure')
print("\n".join(errors or ["Success"]))
```